# Oauth 2.0 for customer portals

Tags: force.com-sites, sandbox, oauth2, portal, user

Currently I'm using apigee console to test my API REST resources. the Oauth works great when I login with a "salesforce" licensed user, but if I tried to log in with a portal user it does not let me in. Seems like I'm not setting correctly the URL for authentication. I know portal user must authenticate using the force.com url and not login.salesforce nor test.salesforce URL, so what's the correct URL to do the authentication against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try {siteurl}/services/oauth2/authorize as the oauth endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly new article that describes this and check the comments section also for common mistakes and fixes.

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html

The URL needs to be:

```
https://mysite.secure.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```